# Create a list object of sheets in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I want to run a for loop in vba which contain some of the sheets of the workbook,not all. So, for that I don't know how to create a list object. I am able to loop across all the sheets in the workbook using this the following code but I don't how to select some particular sheets.

```
For Each ws In Worksheets
```

Comment: Then this [tutorial](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-worksheet/) is for you

Comment: what are the criteria fro wanted sheets (or unwanted ones)?

Comment: I know the name of the sheet, the name can be excel defined sheet names or it can be VBA properties names of the sheets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this, where you create an array. Excel VBA has a limited number of data structures that you can use. An Array is the most common that suits your needs. You declare the array then loop through it. The below is a simple example that solves your problem.

```
Sub SelectSheet()

Dim SheetList(1 To 3) As String

SheetList(1) = "Sheet1"
SheetList(2) = "Sheet3"
SheetList(3) = "Sheet6"


For i = 1 To 3
    Sheets(SheetList(i)).Select
    Range("C3").FormulaR1C1 = "Here"

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of sheet order can there be any other way to select the sheet, say sheet name(excel name) or the vba sheet name(which are fixed irrespective of order).

Comment: @Karan The "Sheet1" is the Excel Sheet name, as it appears in normal view - not the order.  That would be `Worksheets(1)` etc.  You can also use the likes of `Sheet1.Name` to get the Excel Sheet name of the Worksheet.  Or, if you want to store them long-term and are worried about the User changing the name, then you can store them in an object: `Dim wsCollection As Object: Set wsCollection  = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Split("Sheet1|Sheet3", "|")): MsgBox wsCollection.Count`  (The `:` lets you put multiple lines on one line, useful for code in SO comments - the opposite of `_`)